# Rendering and visualization of orbitals of an atom?

Tags: orbitals, reference-request, software

I am looking for program that would display and render the orbitals of an atom.

Preferably display all orbitals. Specifically Argon.

Its not duplicate. I am looking for visual appealing rendered orbitals (hydrogen like) rather than exactness of the levels. And I would like to know which program will do it ?

Comment: There are many programs for 3D graphics, but that's not chemical stuff.

Comment: Yeah, I like how the accepted answer for the question they pointed you to was basically "No, you cannot visualize an atom" - which is BS.  You can visualize it.  Can you visualize the many-electron wave function? No, but you can plot the orbitals, and chemists do so all the time, understanding that they are just approximations to reality.  Assuming you don't have expensive software like Gaussian, you can use [this freeware](http://www.orbitals.com/orb/ov.htm) - which gives you 3D versions of [these](http://www.orbitals.com/orb/orbtable.htm) 2D plots.

Comment: Thank you. The orbital viwer program is ok it has 3D but i dont see a way to put several orbitals on one atom and display them.  I can generate hydrogen like orbitals in matlab but the rendering is not so good.